# To-do list item text overlaps with text of following list item

Tags: html, css

I created a to-do list with jQuery and Bootstrap. If you enter text longer than a single line in the list container, whatever doesn't fit in the first line overlaps with existing list item text in the following one.

Here's my CSS for `ul` and `li` elements (view [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/NYLMwW) for full code):

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  /* distance from the top of the first line of text to the top of the second */
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #666;
}
```

```js
$(function() {

  let degree = 90;

  // Rotates '+' and drops down or recloses input box on click
  $('.fa-plus').on('click', function() {
    if (degree === 135) {
      degree = 45;
    }
    // Sets CSS transform properties. Selector 'this' refers to '+' (with class '.fa-plus') being clicked
    $(this).css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      'transition': '0.2s linear'
    });
    degree += 45;
    // Animates opacity of text box, setting its display style property to none once its opacity reaches 0 if it's visible, or the inverse if already hidden
    $('input[type="text"]').fadeToggle();
  });

  // Checks off specific items upon click and adds them to class 'completed'
  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('completed');
  });

  // Click to delete
  $('ul').on('click', 'span', function(e) {
    // fadeOut() hides element by setting it to transparent
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
      // Removes element along with its data and events
      $(this).remove();
    });
    // Prevents event from bubbling up DOM tree, notifying any parent handlers of it
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', function(e) {
    // If user hits enter...
    if (e.which === 13) {
      // Grabs new to-do list item from input
      let itemText = $(this).val();
      // If nothing in input box, ceases function execution
      if (itemText === '') return;
      // Clears input box
      $(this).val('');
      // Creates new li from input and adds to beginning of ul
      $('ul').prepend('<li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> ' + itemText + '</li>');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  background: #642B73;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #C6426E, #642B73);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #C6426E, #642B73);
}

h1 {
  background: #642B73;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  /* distance from the top of the first line of text to the top of the second */
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #666;
}

/* Sets color of even li elements */
li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

/* Styles Bootstrap trash can icon */
span {
  background: #e74c3c;
  height: 40px;
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

/* When user hovers over li, sets appearance of span content (Bootstrap trash can icon) */
li:hover span {
  width: 40px; /* Applies to icon background */
  opacity: 1.0; 
}

input {
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  /* distance from the top of the first line of text to the top of the second */
  line-height: 40px;
  /* Order: top, right, bottom, left */
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
  /* Includes padding and border in element's total width and height */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #C6426E;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/* Sets appearance of input box boundaries when user clicks inside */
input:focus {
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid #642B73;
  outline: none;
}

.completed {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.fa-plus {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 360px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>To-Do List<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add new">
      <ul>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Work on projects for one hour</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Go for a walk</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Meditate</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Stretch</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just remove the height: 40px rule, I think. Very nice looking example.

Comment: I want to thank you on putting your two different questions on two different SO questions. We allways encounter post with multiple questions that go away form the original.
Hope my answers help and code on! [Link two related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702753/change-placement-of-slide-out-icon-on-to-do-list/49702816#49702816)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to modify your `li` styles.

This will fix it

```
li {
  background: white;
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  color: #666;
}
```

Some other issues might arrrise, like the delete button, but this solves the overlap.

Hope this helps :)

```js
$(function() {

  let degree = 90;

  // Rotates '+' and drops down or recloses input box on click
  $('.fa-plus').on('click', function() {
    if (degree === 135) {
      degree = 45;
    }
    // Sets CSS transform properties. Selector 'this' refers to '+' (with class '.fa-plus') being clicked
    $(this).css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      'transition': '0.2s linear'
    });
    degree += 45;
    // Animates opacity of text box, setting its display style property to none once its opacity reaches 0 if it's visible, or the inverse if already hidden
    $('input[type="text"]').fadeToggle();
  });

  // Checks off specific items upon click and adds them to class 'completed'
  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('completed');
  });

  // Click to delete
  $('ul').on('click', 'span', function(e) {
    // fadeOut() hides element by setting it to transparent
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
      // Removes element along with its data and events
      $(this).remove();
    });
    // Prevents event from bubbling up DOM tree, notifying any parent handlers of it
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', function(e) {
    // If user hits enter...
    if (e.which === 13) {
      // Grabs new to-do list item from input
      let itemText = $(this).val();
      // If nothing in input box, ceases function execution
      if (itemText === '') return;
      // Clears input box
      $(this).val('');
      // Creates new li from input and adds to beginning of ul
      $('ul').prepend('<li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> ' + itemText + '</li>');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  background: #642B73;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #C6426E, #642B73);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #C6426E, #642B73);
}

h1 {
  background: #642B73;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*Edited class*/

li {
  background: white;
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  color: #666;
}


/* Sets color of even li elements */

li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}


/* When user hovers over li, sets appearance of span content (Bootstrap trash can icon) */

li:hover span {
  width: 40px;
  /* Applies to icon background */
  opacity: 1.0;
}


/* Styles Bootstrap trash can icon */

span {
  background: #e74c3c;
  height: 40px;
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

input {
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  /* distance from the top of the first line of text to the top of the second */
  line-height: 40px;
  /* Order: top, right, bottom, left */
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
  /* Includes padding and border in element's total width and height */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #C6426E;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}


/* Sets appearance of input box boundaries when user clicks inside */

input:focus {
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid #642B73;
  outline: none;
}

.completed {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.fa-plus {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 360px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>To-Do List</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>To-Do List<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add new">
    <ul>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Work on projects for one hour</li>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Go for a walk</li>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Meditate</li>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Stretch</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like it worked, please do not forget to upvote and accepting the answer unless you still need something else. In that case I'll be more than happy to help you. Thak you

Comment: It worked, thanks! The only thing is I removed display: flex from the li and it didn't seem to affect anything (updated my CodePen), so I'm not sure if there would be an advantage to keeping that in.

Comment: Also was able to remove min-height without a problem. Replacing min-height with line-height as all that was needed.