# Change placement of slide-out icon on to-do list

Tags: html, css

I created a to-do list with jQuery and Bootstrap. When you hover over a list item, a trashcan icon (added to the HTML inside a `span` element within each of the the `li` elements) slides out on the left side and pushes the list toward the right. I would like to instead have it slide out from the right side, without moving the text in each list item (appearing over top of it). How can this be accomplished?

Here's the relevant code (view [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/NYLMwW) for more):

HTML

```
  <ul>
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Work on projects for one hour</li>
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Go for a walk</li>
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Meditate</li>
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Stretch</li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
/* Styles Bootstrap trash can icon */
span {
  background: #e74c3c;
  height: 40px;
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

/* When user hovers over li, sets appearance of span content (Bootstrap trash can icon) */
li:hover span {
  width: 40px; /* Applies to icon background */
  opacity: 1.0; 
}
```

Comment: I want to thank you on putting your two different questions on two different SO questions. We allways encounter post with multiple questions that go away form the original.
Hope my answers help and code on! [Link two related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702735/to-do-list-item-text-overlaps-with-text-of-following-list-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to change the `span` from sides

First we need to turn the `li` to a `relative` position

```
li {
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Then we can change thwe side of the span

```
span {
  margin-right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
$(function() {

  let degree = 90;

  // Rotates '+' and drops down or recloses input box on click
  $('.fa-plus').on('click', function() {
    if (degree === 135) {
      degree = 45;
    }
    // Sets CSS transform properties. Selector 'this' refers to '+' (with class '.fa-plus') being clicked
    $(this).css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      'transition': '0.2s linear'
    });
    degree += 45;
    // Animates opacity of text box, setting its display style property to none once its opacity reaches 0 if it's visible, or the inverse if already hidden
    $('input[type="text"]').fadeToggle();
  });

  // Checks off specific items upon click and adds them to class 'completed'
  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('completed');
  });

  // Click to delete
  $('ul').on('click', 'span', function(e) {
    // fadeOut() hides element by setting it to transparent
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
      // Removes element along with its data and events
      $(this).remove();
    });
    // Prevents event from bubbling up DOM tree, notifying any parent handlers of it
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', function(e) {
    // If user hits enter...
    if (e.which === 13) {
      // Grabs new to-do list item from input
      let itemText = $(this).val();
      // If nothing in input box, ceases function execution
      if (itemText === '') return;
      // Clears input box
      $(this).val('');
      // Creates new li from input and adds to beginning of ul
      $('ul').prepend('<li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> ' + itemText + '</li>');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  background: #642B73;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #C6426E, #642B73);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #C6426E, #642B73);
}

h1 {
  background: #642B73;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
   background: white;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #666;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

/* Sets color of even li elements */
li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

/* Styles Bootstrap trash can icon */
span {
  background: #e74c3c;
  height: 40px;
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  /* margin-right: 20px; */
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

/* When user hovers over li, sets appearance of span content (Bootstrap trash can icon) */
li:hover span {
  width: 40px; /* Applies to icon background */
  opacity: 1.0; 
}

input {
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  /* distance from the top of the first line of text to the top of the second */
  line-height: 40px;
  /* Order: top, right, bottom, left */
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
  /* Includes padding and border in element's total width and height */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #C6426E;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/* Sets appearance of input box boundaries when user clicks inside */
input:focus {
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid #642B73;
  outline: none;
}

.completed {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.fa-plus {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 360px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>To-Do List<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add new">
      <ul>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Work on projects for one hour</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Go for a walk</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Meditate</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Stretch</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like it worked, please do not forget to upvote and accepting the answer unless you still need something else. In that case I'll be more than happy to help you. Thak you